# Remove automatic Azure Front Door endpoint if the associated storage account has been deleted

Tags: azure, storage, azure-front-door

Is the Azure Front Door endpoint automatically removed if the associated storage account has been renamed or deleted?

If not, does that mean If I delete the storage account (associated with Azure FD) and then recreate a sensitive storage account with the same old name, it will be inadvertently exposed to the internet?

Are there any protections I can put in place to avoid these scenarios?

Many Thanks,

Regards

Excepted that Azure Front Door endpoint doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Azure Front Door endpoint automatically removed if the associated storage account has been renamed or deleted?

I created front door associated with storage, when I delete the storage account ***it will not remove automatically the associated Azure Front Door endpoint*** like below:

[image]

> When you delete the storage account associated with an Azure Front Door service and later recreate a storage account with the same name.

Yes, it is possible that the new storage account could be inadvertently exposed to the internet it gets associated with the same Azure Front Door endpoint like below:

I recreated a storage account with same name it gets associated with the same Azure Front Door endpoint and its work:

[image]

Azure front door will not automatically remove endpoint. To avoid this, you can delete like below:

Create new endpoint like below:

[image]

In policy if front door is associated remove like below:

[image]

Now you can delete front door endpoint and then delete storage account once to recreate sensitive storage account with the same old name it will associate with new endpoint like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any queries @Tran Tony ?